# How to resize the image and page to fit for all android screens in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**problem** trying to make fit the image over some text which is like 2/3rd of the screen here's the link  of image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJMS2.jpg

layout is designed like

```
<View style={styles.container} maintainAspectRatio={true} source={logotwo}>

        <Container >  <Image source={logo} maintainAspectRatio={true} style={styles.logo}>
        </Image>
          <View >
            <Content >

              <Text style={styles.boldtext}>SOME TITLE</Text>
              <Text style={styles.subtext} adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} numberOfLines={3}>
                A str agfdgdfgfdgfsdgsfdggdgfg(some long sentence) nance.</Text>
              <View>
                <Button style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => { this._signIn() } }>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#fff' }}>
                    LOGIN 
            </Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
            </Content>
          </View>

        </Container >
      </View>
```

and style for the same is

```
  container: {
     resizeMode: 'cover', height: null,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },

  logo: {
    width: null,
    height: 398,
resizeMode: 'stretch',
  },
 boldtext: {

    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 23,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
  ,
  subtext: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    opacity: 0.7,
    textAlign: 'center',

  },
button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 70,
    fontSize: 50,
  }
```

i tried adjusting the width and height manually but resolution is not matched up with various screens i tested on.

Please suggest some good standard to follow the same for all screens in my app.

Comment: Did you try to use "@media" style tag? ex:
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

Comment: No, but i am new to React native and javascript, can you elaborate little more about ? thanks

Comment: with @media tag, you can specify the styles specific to the device width. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
Try these.

Comment: tried using for height: PixelRatio utility class but not helpful.

Comment: My bad. Looks like react-native has a different way to specify media tags. You need to install plugins.